# std::map's std::_Rb_tree copy causing recursion resulting in a SEGSEV with a 4000+ deep coredump-callstack

Tags: c++11, std, embedded-linux, stdmap, red-black-tree

We have std::map used and copied in few places, In a unknown scenario we received SEGSEV, with core dump showing log. On analyzing the core dump, even the gdb crashes. The Red black tree's M_Copy can cause some infinite recursion?  Typically the list contains not more than 5 items. Any clues on which problem can cause this infinite recursion in the internals of std::_Rb_tree's implementation?

```
#0  0x76ac0450 in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x76800010, bytes=bytes@entry=24)
    at malloc.c:3293
        nb = <optimized out>
        idx = <optimized out>
        bin = <optimized out>
        victim = <optimized out>
        size = <optimized out>
        victim_index = <optimized out>
        remainder = <optimized out>
        remainder_size = <optimized out>
        block = <optimized out>
        bit = <optimized out>
        map = <optimized out>
        fwd = <optimized out>
        bck = <optimized out>
        errstr = 0x0
        __func__ = "_int_malloc"
#1  0x76ac2d8c in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=24) at malloc.c:2892
        ar_ptr = 0x76800010
        victim = <optimized out>
        hook = <optimized out>
        __func__ = "__libc_malloc"
#2  0x76c68570 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x003552c0 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > >::_M_clone_node(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > const*) ()
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00355304 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > >::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >*) ()
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00355324 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > >::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >*) ()
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x00355324 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >, s---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
td::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > >::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >*) ()
No symbol table info available.
#7  0x00355324 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > >::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >*) ()
No symbol table info available.
#8  0x00355324 in std::_Rb_tree<unsigned long, std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >, std::less<unsigned long>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > >::_M_copy(std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> > const*, std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<unsigned long const, CObject*> >*) ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Below is _Rb_tree's _M_copy implementation any suggestions?

```
    _Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KoV, _Compare, _Alloc>::
    _M_copy(_Const_Link_type __x, _Link_type __p)
    {
      // Structural copy.  __x and __p must be non-null.
      _Link_type __top = _M_clone_node(__x);
      __top->_M_parent = __p;

     try
     {
      if (__x->_M_right)
         __top->_M_right = _M_copy(_S_right(__x), __top);
         __p = __top;
         __x = _S_left(__x);

         while (__x != 0)
         {
          _Link_type __y = _M_clone_node(__x);
          __p->_M_left = __y;
           __y->_M_parent = __p;
           if (__x->_M_right)
           __y->_M_right = _M_copy(_S_right(__x), __y);
           __p = __y;
           __x = _S_left(__x);
         }
     }
    catch(...)
    {
       _M_erase(__top);
       __throw_exception_again;
     }
       return __top;
    }
```

P.S I doubled the stack size, now it shows 8000+ entries of stack trace afterwards gdb crashes again.

Comment: "In a unknown scenario" will be really hard to tell, you should first try to identify the dataset that causes the bug. A possible answer could be that the compare method you used to order your map is not a strict weak ordering.

Comment: possible scenario is std::map = operator being called.

Comment: Can infinite recursion happen in Rbtree implementation of copy?

Comment: There are little chances that the implementation of std map is at fault. What you need to investigate is what the map that you are using contains :
Are the key values are a strict weak ordering? 
Are the key/data object can be allocated (see the allocator of map)?  You can trace it with a debbuger

Comment: Other question that you do not specified : are you accessing your map from multiple threads ? If it is the case, are you sure you don't create a case where 2 threads try to alter the map ?

Comment: @Nico238 at the time of issue occurrence, there was 1 item only in the map, and its accessed from single thread only.  It happens very rare, unable to recreate the issue.

Comment: have you try to run your software under a memory profiler such as Valgrind, Purify or insure++? It can be a memory corruption that happens before, but the software runs until it reached the corrupted memory.
As I said in my first comment it is really hard to find a good way to help you on a non-reproducible bug

Comment: Or some evil cast or dangling pointer/reference use happened to change some memory that belonged to the map implementation, breaking the invariants it relies on. There are really too many possibilities to guess at, unless you can come up with a small program that demonstrates the same problem.

Comment: So heapcorruption could be a cause, I'm analyzing code with valgrind. Thanks for your inputs Nico123 , aschelper